# Is there a way to make Conditional Formatting ignore the FollowedHyperlink flag?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, conditional-formatting

I have a table of contents in Excel 365. In the table, column 2 contains the names of worksheets and column 3 contains the names of tables and/or named ranges in the associated worksheet. I used the `HYPERLINK` function to link each cell to its specific component: hyperlinks for the worksheet column go to cell A1 on the associated worksheet; hyperlinks in the table/named range column go to that specific table or named range.

Since this results in several repeats of worksheet names, I used conditional formatting to change the text to white when the worksheet name is a repeat of the one directly above it. This makes it look more like an outline. It works like a charm up until the point that I click on the link in a repeated cell, making it a FollowedHyperlink. When I return to the table, this is no longer whited out. Is there a way to make these stay white, even after they've been followed?

Here's the formula I used for the conditional formatting rule applied it throughout the range `=$C$6:$C$24`:

```
=C5=C6
```

Here's what it looks like before I click one of the whited-out cells:

[image]

Here's what it looks like after I click one of the whited-out cells:

[image]

Comment: [THIS](https://superuser.com/a/819931/652108) may be of interest

Comment: Definitely of interest. Unfortunately, now the followed hyperlinks just change to whatever other color I selected (blue, in this case) instead of purple. I could change it to white, but then if the user clicks the first listing, it would disappear after being followed.

Comment: Made some changes to my approach and re-asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101044/can-i-use-vba-to-make-excel-forget-that-it-followed-a-hyperlink/60101575

Answer (score 0):

Urdearboy posted a link showing how to change the style of a followed link.

https://superuser.com/questions/728825/how-do-i-prevent-excel-from-changing-the-color-of-a-clicked-link/819931#819931

It is probably the best solution without using VBA.

But if you want some not control over it, if for example, you may want all links in a table if contents to be uniform color regardless if they were taken or not, but you want links in the rest of the book to change.  That's as easy as a single line of VBA in the worksheet's SheetFollowHyperlink event:

```
Target.Range.Font.Color = vbBlue
```

And if you wanted to apply it to the entire workbook instead of a single sheet you would put it in the workbook's SheetFollowHyperlink event.

But if you want to be a little creative...

You could make the link disappear by blending it with the background color:

```
Target.Range.Font.Color = Target.Range.Interior.Color
```

Or you can draw attention to it, by changing the back color:

```
Target.Range.Interior.Color = vbYellow
```

Really, your imagination is the only limit.  You can do just about anything you'd ever want to do ( and a lot more of things you would never want to do).

Comment: This provided an interesting avenue to explore, but it didn't work with the `HYPERLINK` function. Apparently, Excel views that kind of hyperlink differently than on created through the dialog. I converted everything over using the `Hyperlinks.Add` method in VBA, and can get it to change the colors as you say. However, as one might expect, the color remains changed after sorting the table differently. It is still overriding the conditional formatting. Is there a way to make it stop doing that...to make Excel stop seeing the hyperlink as a followed hyperlink?

Comment: Made some changes to my approach and re-asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60101044/can-i-use-vba-to-make-excel-forget-that-it-followed-a-hyperlink/60101575

Comment: @rmbradburn Yes there is, but you will not like it.  Restarting Excel will wipe the followed status.

Comment: @rmbradburn I enjoyed reading through your other question.  That was some good work pulling on different threads until you found a workable solution. I hope it serves you well.

Comment: Thanks. I enjoy the puzzle. :)

Comment: @rmbradburn heh, if you enjoy puzzles... I'm currently stuck on one:   how to pass arguments to a different workbook with `OnAction` or `Application Run` (this includes `Application.OnTime` by extension)  Ironically, I encountered the problem trying to answer a tangentially related question that has since been marked "duplicate".   If I can't solve it by the end of the day then this will be the first question I create on SO. You can read up on it here... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60093107/run-a-macro-in-an-addin-from-a-button-on-an-excel-sheet/60093733#60093733

Comment: Sounds a bit beyond my current level, but I bookmarked it and may play with it later. For now, I've avoided my actual assignments for too long and need to knock some stuff out at work.