# Run a macro in an AddIn from a button on an Excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to run a macro defined in an AddIn from a button on an excel sheet. I tried to enter the name of the macro in the "assign macro" dialog box that appears when right clicking the button (I don't know the exact English title of the dialog as I'm working with a German Excel version) in the formats 
`AddInName!MacroName` and
`'AddInName'!MacroName`.
In both cases the name of the AddIn is stripped away automatically when I reopen the dialog.
The format `"'AddInName'!MacroName"` was rejected as "a too complex formula"

On the machine on that I am developing the AddIn this works but on another machine where the AddIn is running without problems this particular function does not work.

Is there a way to access a macro inside of an AddIn that may be located at different locations on different machines (C:/user/"user_name".../AddIns) ?

Comment: You need a procedure for the button in your Excel file. This procedure than can run the macro in the add-in. See the linked answer (above your question).

Comment: @Peh: That might work, but then the excel sheet has to be an xlsm file what I wanted to avoid.

Comment: Well, I thought you were looking for an alternative to the syntax which is `'your_addin.xlsm'!Some_Macro` to call a macro in another file. Make sure the add-in is loaded, because you cannot run the macro in the add-in if it is unloaded.

Comment: The AddIn is loaded on the other machine, otherwise it would not work (beside the problem described above). I would accept if it is simply not possible to call a macro in an AddIn from a *xlsx file. But at least on my machine there seems a mysterious way to make it work. That's why I thought it could be possible to make it work on other machines as well.

Comment: I see no reason why it should not be possible. The add-in name needs to be the same on both machines. To link the button you only use the add-in file name (not the full path). And it should work (as on your machine). • What happens if you click the button? Does it throw an error? • If there is no error make sure that the macro you call is not the issue. Test it with a simple macro that only shows a message box and does nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Long story, made very ***[long]***: maybe.

You'll have to work out the file sharing and permissions between the two computers but you can use an AddIn on a shared network drive so it is entirely possible.

I would caution against using the same AddIn simultaneously between computers.  It would be easier, safer, and more stable to make a copy.

You're on the right track with your string creation, but rather than adding it in the macro selection box, add it to the `OnAction` property of the button in the worksheet's code module.

I'm going from memory so I might be mistaken but I'm pretty sure your string will be built like this...

```
"'[addin.xlam]!project.module.macro'"     \edit: tested and confirmed not to work
```

Note that there are there ticks, it is an outer "double quote" encapsulating an inner 'single quote'

You can also pass arguments to the macro with an appropriately built string too, it's relatively easy when using variables or integers but it gets tricky when you start using string literals.

Just finished my post to read this:

"@Peh: That might work, but then the excel sheet has to be an xlsm file what I wanted to avoid. – chrmue 9 mins ago"

Obviously that rules out my entire solution.

---

I spent several hours on this and all I've done is run around in circles.

The comments in my code appear to be wrong, and while I all passing parameters in my working code, I am only doing it within the same workbook and have failed every attempt to send them to another workbook via `OnAction` and even `Application.Run`

It may be a fools errand but I'm convinced it's possible so in but giving up.

---

I have a button on the sheet:

```
Shapes.Add xlButtonControl
```

It passes two arguments through a procedure:

```
OnAction = "'passthroughme ""passing"", ""through"" '"
```

But hithertofor, that's as far as it goes.  No success reaching external workbook's while also including arguments.

I also have several examples of existing code that works just fine, but I haven't been able to get any is them to pass arguments to an external workbook:

```
Select Case Application.Run(testingFunction)

Application.Run procToCall, procArgs

testResult = Application.Run(testingFunction, testingArgs)

Application.Run "extractPDF." & loPDFvendors.ListColums(gTCN_PDFMAP_PROCLIST).DataBodyRange(mSupplierIndex), ws
```

Not giving up yet, but I am defeated for the moment

Comment: And you should check your syntax, I'm pretty sure it should be `"'addin.xlam'!project.module.macro"`, so the addin name is enclosed in `' '` not the total string, and the `[ ]` need to be removed (probably mixed it up with formulas where you need them for the file name followed by a sheet name like `='[file.xlsm]Sheet1'!A1`)

Comment: @Pᴇʜ That's funny because I doubted my memory when I wrote that.  But I spent some time refreshing my memory when I got back to my computer. i looked up a project from a month ago and found my code with comments confirming successfull test cases with brackets and without when encased as suggested in my post and zero successful tests when when not encased.  Yes, this is different from the macro window - but there distinction is that I'm passing arguments.  I'll update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Actually you got me doubting and I made a quick test: Opened 2 files from scratch. Added a button to sheet 1 in `file1.xlsm` and added a sub with `Buttons(1).OnAction = "'file2.xlsm'!test"`. And added `Public Sub test()` into a module of `file2.xlsm` throwing a message box. And it did. • If I try your syntax instead I immediately get a runtime error 1004 trying to set the `.OnAction` for the button. Tested on Office Pro 2019 latest build.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ heh, we think alike.  I have been testing too.  You will not get that error if you use my syntax **and** include an argument (the argument is enclosed in two double quotes) but you do have to drop the exclamation  `.OnAction = "'[File2.xlsm]VBAProject.Module1.test ""send this""'"` However, I have not updated my answer yet because the button is not successfully passing the string.

Comment: But I think that is because if I try this `.OnAction = "'[File2.xlsm]VBAProject.Module1.test ""send this""'"`  and click the button I get an error because he tries to run a macro named `'[File2.xlsm]VBAProject.Module1.test ""send this""'` in `file1.xlsm`. *Actually that is what the error messag states*: Macro `file1.xlsm!'[File2.xlsm]VBAProject.Module1.test ""send this""'` cannot be run …

Comment: Yeah, I am seeing the same thing on Office 365 Pro Plus and it is bugging me.  I'll revisit this when I get back to the office and can review my project.  It was built with Office 2013 but I'm not expecting that to make a difference.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Updated my "answer" with the current state of affairs.  The inline comments showing successful tests results were wrong.  All testing within last two days supports everything you've shown.  It seems I've never actually passed arguments to another workbook via OnAction or Application.Run - running on premise that it is possible but have no results to show it.  This is shaping up to be my first SO question.

Comment: Just for your interest: You can run a macro in another workbook and submit a parameter either with `Application.Run "'MyTestFile.xlsm'!MyTestProject.MyTestModule.MyTestProcedure", "Test Parameter 1"` or for a button action with `Buttons(1).OnAction = "'MyTestFile.xlsm'!'MyTestProject.MyTestModule.MyTestProcedure ""Test Parameter 1""'"`