# Can I use VBA to make Excel forget that it followed a hyperlink?

Tags: excel, vba, conditional-formatting

I'm using conditional formatting to affect font color on certain cells containing hyperlinks in a table. When I follow the hyperlink, though, it overrides the conditional formatting in the cell, which is undesired.

The conditional formatting is essentially making the text invisible if the cell immediately above the current cell has the same value. It uses a formula (`=C5=C6`) applied throughout the range (`$C$6:$C$24`).

Things I've tried:

- Closing and re-opening the file fixes the issue because it resets all
  the followed hyperlinks back to normal hyperlinks. However, I don't
  want to have to close and re-open all the time.
- I can use the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event to change the font color back, but when I sort the table differently (thus changing how the conditional formatting should act), the conditional formatting is
  still disabled -- now in favor of the programatically-applied font
  color.

This question is essentially an update of my previous post ([Is there a way to make Conditional Formatting ignore the FollowedHyperlink flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60086285/is-there-a-way-to-make-conditional-formatting-ignore-the-followedhyperlink-flag)). I'm no longer using the `HYPERLINK` formula, since that wasn't allowing me to use the `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` option provided in an answer.

I've also read through the provided SuperUser thread (https://superuser.com/questions/728825/how-do-i-prevent-excel-from-changing-the-color-of-a-clicked-link/819931), which provided some other interesting avenues to pursue, but didn't quite get me where I needed to be. I'm specifically asking now if I can reset Excel's memory of which hyperlinks have been followed.

This is want I want, both before and after clicking the link:

[image]

This is the undesired behavior that I get after clicking the link:

[image]

Comment: Sorry...typo in the original post. The `Worksheet_FollowHyperlink` event was what I tried (not the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event mentioned in the original post...although I did try that as well).

Comment: Are these hyperlinks to URL's, or to places in the workbook ?

Comment: Places in the workbook. The first column contains links to `$A$1` in the listed worksheet; the second column to tables and/or named ranges.

Comment: I just discovered that  a purple, "followed hyperlink" cell has the "Hyperlink" style applied if I type `?selection.style` in the Immediate window, and the blue color ("12673797") if I try `?selection.font.color`...even though I'm clearly seeing purple on the screen. How is Excel displaying these as purple if it isn't changing the style or color of the font?

Comment: Same is true using `?selection.displayformat.style` and `?selection.displayformat.font.color`.

Comment: This is a great question - looks like if you clear the format of the hyperlink and then "re-apply" the hyperlink style, Excel still remembers it as a followed hyperlink.

Comment: Thanks. I finally developed a work-around as listed below, but would still love to get a more optimal answer and understand what exactly Excel is doing if it isn't using the "Followed Hyperlink" style or color, but still making cells appear that way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't disclosed what format you are using in your CF, but I'm guessing it's setting text colour to white.

A Far better general format for hiding a cells contents is `;;;`.  If you use this in your CF, then a followed hyperlink remains hidden

Comment: Exactly right about using white to make the text disappear into the background. Where are you inputting `;;;`?

Comment: Interesting. I like that it hides the contents; however, if I come back to click the link a second time, I end up with an error: "Cannot open the specified file."

Comment: @rmbradburn you enter it through the conditional format dialog. Re the error, that can not have anything to do with the format, must be related to your hyperlink

Comment: Thanks. I'll dig into it tomorrow. Oddly, the error only occurred after I changed to the format you suggest. When I removed it and went back to just using white for the font, the error didn't occur anymore. I'll kick it around a bit more tomorrow and see if I can figure it out. Thanks for your suggestion!

Comment: @rmbradburn the error is possibly a hangover from other things you've tried. For this solution, there's no need for any VBA, and no need to modify cell format (other than in the CF).  I've tested this on a new sheet, and see no errors.

Comment: Turns out I had edited @BigBen's VBA as I was wrapping my mind around it. Had removed the `.Address` portion. Even after that, I'd swear it was still working with CF changing the font color, but not with `;;;` even though that makes no sense. Whatever the case, it's all fixed now and functioning properly using `;;;`. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2):

Something like the following *seems* to work to keep the style of the hyperlink unchanged - basically just re-add the hyperlink to the same cell:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)
    With Target
        .Range.Hyperlinks.Add .Range, .Address, .SubAddress, , .TextToDisplay
    End With
End Sub
```

`ScreenTip` was causing issues so I intentionally omitted it - the hyperlink I tested it with had no screen tip.

If in fact this does work for your case, to make it more robust I would test the length of the `SubAddress`, `ScreenTip`, and `TextToDisplay` before attempting to use them in `Hyperlinks.Add`. They are all optional parameters, and the hyperlink clicked might not have those properties to begin with.

Comment: So far, this seems to come closest to what I'm looking for. It essentially resets the hyperlink without really specifying any different format for the cells. I wish there were a way to directly interact with whatever flag Excel has for followed hyperlinks, but this seems like the way to at least do it indirectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This worked for me and did not interfere with conditional formatting:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    With Target.Range
        .Font.Color = vbBlue
        .Font.Underline = True
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So, here's a work-around that I just figured out...finally. Still not the best answer, and still doesn't answer the specific question of how to make Excel forget that it followed a specific link, so I'd love to still see better answers.

But this gets done what I wanted to get done...for the most part.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_FollowHyperlink(ByVal Target As Hyperlink)

    Target.Range.Style = "Followed Hyperlink"

End Sub
```

Setting the style to "Followed Hyperlink" with the code above, surprisingly does the trick. As noted in previous comments, Excel isn't using this style even though it looks like it is. Setting it manually with VBA apparently allows the conditional formatting to function.

Downside: closing and opening the workbook no longer resets the color. A workaround would be to change the "Followed Hyperlink" style to the same as the "Hyperlink" style, but then no links throughout the workbook would have the purple color. So, this is still not the most optimal answer.

EDIT: I should make it clear that using this option applies the "Followed Hyperlink" style (purple text). It doesn't override the conditional formatting, though, which was the biggest part of the problem.

Comment: What color are you setting the conditional formatting to? (I'm using white to make the text disappear.)

Comment: Ohhhh I missed that you were using conditional formatting... sorry.

Comment: Yeah, that's a critical element to this inquiry. The above answer does make the text purple, but it doesn't override the conditional formatting like what I was experiencing in the original question. That allows the conditional formatting to still work to make duplicate cells "invisible" (white text).